# Regex Help: Adding directory path prefix to PDF file links

Tags: regex

I've got a project where a ton of PDF files were added right into the /public_html directory.

I've cleaned them up into a folder:
/public_html/external

Now, I've got links like this:

```
href = "/some-pdf-file.pdf"
```

I need to change them all using Regex (Joomla+ReReplacer) to:

```
href = "/external/some-pdf-file.pdf"
```

I'm willing to bet it's a simple one-line-regex command and I'm going to feel like an idiot once I see it.

Comment: what've you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the setup is, but here's a guess in JavaScript. Please adapt as needed.

`source.replace(/(href\s+=\s+")([^"]*\.pdf)(")/, "$1/external$2$3");`

Probably a bit overkill, but you get the idea.

Comment: I don't see any reference to "pdf" in your example...?  Wouldn't this change all links?  

I'm using the ReReplacer component in Joomla to execute this.  I'm not sure if that would be considered javascript.  But I'm using a find & replace sequence... here is a link to ReReplacer:

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/rereplacer

Comment: Looks like you can use regex with it, going by the [tutorial](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/rereplacer#tutorial).

So the search field would be: `/(href\s+=\s+")([^"]*)(")/` and the replace field would be `\1/external\2\3`. Does that make any sense to you? Cos I don't really know the specifics of ReReplacer...

Comment: I still don't see a reference to PDF files in your "search field" example.  Wouldn't this go through and change ALL links, not just the PDF links?

Comment: It would! Sorry about that--wasn't clear on the specifics of what you needed. 

I've fixed the regex in the answer: `/(href\s+=\s+")([^"]*\.pdf)(")/` That should work fine with the same replace field.

Comment: I tried the search field: 
`/(href\s+=\s+")([^"]*)(")/`

And the replace field:
`\1/external\2\3`

No luck... any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe they should just be strings. Have you looked at that tutorial or the docs?

Comment: The only thing I see in the settings - I'm not sure what you mean by "strings" - but I have a yes/no toggle that says "use 'newline' modifier"

Comment: A string is just text. As in a "string" of characters.

To be honest, I have no idea what ReReplacer is, how it's used, or what you can do with it. From what I've seen on their site there is a way of using regular expressions with it, but I don't know any more than that.

As you've used it already, and you have it in front of you (and maybe you have more documentation to look at), you're in a much better position than me to figure out how to use it.

Comment: I'm happy to help with things I know about (like the regex stuff). But from here on, I don't think I can be much help. Maybe you could post a separate question on using regex with ReReplacer and see if anyone else can help you with that?

Comment: I'll circle back once I find a solution.  I'm currently working with the ReReplacer developer and I had to give them admin access to the site to look under the hood.